# Should display:none element still have length = 1?

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if an element with `display: none` should have a length of 1 in JavaScript. I though `display: none` was like removing an element from the document and the known universe.

e.g.

```
$('.element').hide();  // jQuery sets to display: none;
console.log($('element').length); // returns 1
```

Comment: jQuery.hide() does not remove element from dom, it sets CSS prop `display` to `none`. Maybe you want jQyery.remove() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `display:none` property is just use to hide the element, it will not remove the element form the `DOM`. 
If you open the console and look into the `Elements` tab you will still see the element with `display:none`.

If you want to remove the element then you could use javascript to remove it from `DOM`.

**Example**

```
let elem = document.querySelector(`<css selector>`);
elem.remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

All that `display: none` does is it changes the CSS style property of the element. The element still exists in the document, so it's still possible to select it with jQuery or a DOM method. Eg, both

```
<body>
  <div>foo</div>
</body>
```

and

```
<body>
  <div style="display: none">foo</div>
</body>
```

exist in the document.

If you want to actually *remove* the element from the DOM, use `.remove()` (in both jQuery and built-in JS):

```
$('.element').remove();
```

or

```
document.querySelector('.element').remove();
```

Both of those will result in the DOM changing from

```
<body>
  <div class="element">foo</div>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: And to show the element again, you can call `$('.element').show();`

Answer (score 0):

One more thing is when you use the

```
    $('.element').remove();
or  
    document.querySelector('.element').remove();
```

be aware that: The remove() method removes the selected elements, **including all text and child nodes.**